# My father was naturalized: am I British otherwise than by descent?

Tags: united-kingdom, citizenship, uk-citizens, uk-citizenship

I am a British citizen who was under 18 when my father applied for naturalization in 1979. I was registered on his form, and then I (as well as my father) was given citizenship when the naturalization came through in 1982.

Am I a British citizen by descent or not?

Comment: That reads like you were naturalised in your own right, which is indeed 'other than by descent'

Comment: @user16259 have you looked at the nationality act?  It's far from simple to work through all the conditions.

Answer (score 1):

Who is a British citizen "by descent" under the current British Nationality Act of 1981 is specified in section 14. It's kind of hard to follow but none of the cases apply to you. You were born before 1983 when the act came into effect, and you became a British citizen when the act came into effect, so subsection (1)(b) is most relevant, but none of the cases in there apply to you (you were registered as a minor under section 7 of the 1948 Act, not section 5, and you had right of abode in the UK under the Immigration Act of 1971, section 2 subsection (1)(a), because you were a CUKC through being registered in the UK).

Answer (score 0):

According to the British Nationality Act (1948), which I was registered under: "Registration of minors" does not fall under Citizenship by birth or descent. So that means I am British otherwise than by descent.

Comment: But the British nationality act 1981 may have changed that (it's unlikely, but possible).